# Send multiple spreadsheet rows to the same email

Tags: email, html-email, email-attachments, nodemailer, mass-emails

I used the second script (the one with EMAIL_SENT confirmation) from the link below and it worked great).

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails

I need help to edit this same script to send just one email if the email address is the same, currently it sends multiple emails to the same user, this could flood their inbox.

Comment: Hi, Can anyone assist, this is kind of urgent and I am new to this and keep trying, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Is it possible for you to edit the spreadsheet? It would be easier and safer to de-duplicate a spreadsheet. There should be a button for this already.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, my problem is with this script it sends multiple emails (not duplicates), like if I want a user to receive 5 tasks he/she gets one email for each task (total 5 emails), I want them to get only one consolidated email with all 5 tasks.